# Disabling Resume

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am working with Cocoa, doing some tutorials. My question is how do I stop an application from picking up from where it left off after quitting? Like, how do I reset window size, position, etc?

And how do I set an initial position?

Comment: Why? Those are features built into iOS and Mac OS and users expect it. You should have a very very good reason to go against an OS feature. Just food for though.

Comment: Other Applications or your application ?

Comment: I am currently learning about sizes. So after resizing a window, printing out the size, and quitting (my application), after running it again, it keeps that resized size. I want to disable this explicity for this application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466824/prevent-resume-for-my-cocoa-application/7467045#7467045

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you uncheck the "Restorable" box in IB, the window will always start with the size and position that you set in IB..

Comment: Two drawbacks: (1) You would have to set this for every window, and (2) it would affect your users as well, not simply help you debug the application from a clean state.