# Prevent NSDocument-based app from reopening documents after a crash

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsdocument

I have a read-only music player app for macOS that uses NSDocument to get all the file-handling logic for free.

The problem that I now have is that every time the app crashes (or is stopped by the debugger) while one or more player windows are open, they automatically get reopened when the app is restarted. I don't want that, since it interferes with debugging and legitimate crashes don't really happen with this app.

Apple's NSDocument documentation contains nothing regarding the reopening of files, so I'm out of luck there. Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: I would suggest looking into something in the appDelegate file. If I remember correctly, you can put certain things into there to handle crashing and other similar things.

Comment: Stopping the debugger sends a SIGKILL, which is uncatchable, and applicationDidFinishLaunching is called before the document reopening happens, so no dice.

Comment: Try Xcode -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Options -> Launch application without state restoration.

Comment: That's only valid for the current debugging session, I want it to be disabled for my app only, and forever.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent "Resume" for my Cocoa application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466824/prevent-resume-for-my-cocoa-application)

Answer (score 5):

First create a subclass of `NSDocumentController` and make sure you create an instance of it in `- (void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification` so it becomes the sharedDocumentController. (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373446/how-do-i-use-a-subclass-of-nsdocumentcontroller-in-xcode-4))

Then in you subclass override the restore method:

```
+ (void)restoreWindowWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier state:(NSCoder *)state completionHandler:(void (^)(NSWindow *, NSError *))completionHandler
{
    if (_preventDocumentRestoration) { // you need to decide when this var is true
        completionHandler(nil, [NSError errorWithDomain:NSCocoaErrorDomain code:NSUserCancelledError userInfo:nil]);
    }
    else {
        [super restoreWindowWithIdentifier:identifier state:state completionHandler:completionHandler];
    }
}
```